# How can I specify java interfaces file names using openapi.yaml and swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to generate 2 controller classes for 2 scopes in my project.
I can do that with 2 separate openapi.yaml files, and 2 maven executions.

I'm using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to get it done, and I could only find code that uses swagger.yaml or openapi.yaml with a different plugin.
I can't find this combination, though I'm positive it's possible.

The question is if I have 2 scopes such as 'DB' and 'Browse', and I want to have 2 interfaces created for the 2 scopes such as DBApi.java and BrowseApi.java, how can it be done, and if it can be done using 1 openapi.yaml file?

I did see example projects where 1 openapi.yaml file resulted in PetApi.java and StoreApi.java, but I couldn't find how to configure this in my setup.

Thanks.

The relevant part in the maven pom file is:

```
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>raptor-codegen</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <apiPackage>com.app.seo.graph.rest.v1.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.app.seo.graph.rest.v1.model</modelPackage>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <additional-properties>preAuthorize=hasAuthority,useJsonPropertyOrder=true,resourceMetaType=com.ebay.jaxrs.server.ResourceOperation</additional-properties>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: This may be probably too late but have you tried using `<useTags>true</useTags>` under <configOptions>?

Answer (score 3):

I've used `<useTags>true</useTags>` under `<configOptions>` in my Maven file and it works for me. YAML definition

```
paths:
    '/operation/':
        get:
            tags:
                - Some-Service
```

generates "SomeServiceApi" class name with the `SpringCodegen` generator. Using "openapi-generator-maven-plugin" in the "6.2.0" version.